# picture element srcset responsive image rollovers

Tags: javascript, image, rollovers

I am trying to figure out how to apply an image rollover effect to the picture element in a responsive website.

The question is can an image rollover be applied the scrset attribute in the picture tag?

Working example img tag with javascript rollover effect

```
<img src="media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero.jpg" 
 onmouseover="this.src='media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero-ro.jpg'" 
 onmouseout="this.src='media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero.jpg'" 
 alt=""/>
```

Not working example of picture element with javascript rollover effect

```
<picture>
 <source srcset="media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero-large.jpg" 
 onmouseover="this.src='media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero-large-ro.jpg'" 
 onmouseout="this.src='media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero.jpg'" 
 media="(min-width: 880px)">

 <source srcset="media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero-small.jpg" media="(max-width: 478px)">
 <source srcset="media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero-medium.jpg">

 <!-- fall back -->
 <img srcset="media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero-medium.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions hoe to achieve a rollover effect on the picture tag using the srcset?

The web page has about 12 responsive images that need a rollover effect.

Answer (score 1):

Changing src/srcset is not optimal, even for a single img, since it can abort the download of the image if you hover it or leave it before the download is complete.

I think I would do one of these:

- Clone the picture with `cloneNode(true)` and rewrite the URLs of the clone. When the original picture element receives a `mouseover` event, replace it with the clone. When the clone receives a `mouseout` event, replace it with the original.
- Duplicate the picture in the markup, with the second one representing the hovered image. The second picture has a `hidden` attribute set. Toggle the `hidden` attribute on both elements as appropriate.

In the future, it should be possible to toggle the image with CSS using something like `img:hover { content:image-set(...); }`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<picture id="zen">
 <source class="large" srcset="media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero-large.jpg" media="(min-width: 880px)">

 <source srcset="media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero-small.jpg" media="(max-width: 478px)">
 <source srcset="media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero-medium.jpg">

 <!-- fall back -->
 <img srcset="media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero-medium.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#zen').on('mouseover', function () {
    $(this).find('.large').attr('srcset', 'media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero-large-ro.jpg');
    console.log('mouse over');
  })
  $('#zen').on('mouseout', function () {
    $(this).find('.large').attr('srcset', 'media/images/feature-films/tmbs/zen-zero-large.jpg');
    console.log('mouse out');
  })
});
```

Comment: It's too bad this will cause a double download when you need < medium size. 
And I believe there is nothing to do about it, unless visitors are all on nightly browsers; using the 'srcset' attribute.

Comment: Why would it cause a double download?